# How to give flexbox items the same height as parent element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've been searching online for a while and can't seem to find a solution to this problem. Maybe I'm just confused.

Given the following css, how would one go about vertically centering the text inside each of the colored boxes without changing the vertical height of boxes. If you use "align-items: center;" you shrink the boxes down to the size of the font.

The reason I need to figure this out is because I have the following code:

```
    <div class="navigationBar">
        <div class="centeringContainer">

            <div class="myName">
                John Smith
            </div>


            <div class="centeringContainerTwo">
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>

                <nav class ="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="linkOne"><a href = "">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li class="linkTwo"><a href = "">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li class="linkThree"><a href = "">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="linkFour"><a href = "">Link 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>


                <div class="spacer">
                </div>
                <div class="spacer">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

You can see the accompanying css here:

http://codepen.io/omnomnious/pen/wgzvPv

I want the buttons on the right side of the screen (which have been colored bright blue just to distinguish them), to have the same height as the navigation bar regardless of the viewport size and also have the text vertically centered. That way when I hover over the link, the entire section of the navigation bar which the link covers changes color, instead of just the small box. I would really appreciate any help and feedback on whether or not I'm using flexboxes correctly and if I have bad practice.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick solution is to wrap the anchor text in a `span` element:

```
<li class="linkOne">
     <a href = "">
        <span>Link 1</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRrdaZ?editors=1100)

You need to give all parent elements in the nav bar full height. This is achieved by giving each parent `display: flex`. By making an element a flex container it automatically applies full height to the child (`align-items: stretch`).

The anchor element cannot be both vertically centered and full height. It has to be either one or the other. By wrapping the anchor text in a `span`, you can make the anchor element full height, then vertically center the `span`.

Comment: Oh my god @Michael_B you're a wizard. Can you explain to me the logic behind it? I'm pretty confused with regards to how flexbox works when there are multiple nested children as is the case with the nav, ul, li and a elements.

Comment: I found the reason why the `span` is not needed, in [your latest flexbox-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41661609/2827823) :) ... _Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item._

Comment: @LGSon, As we discussed in a previous conversation, I was getting mixed results in my testing, so I just added the span and it worked consistently across browsers.

Comment: I know ... still, I just had to :)

Answer (score 1):

If you add a height to these rules/elements, and give the anchors `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` to center its text vertical/horizontal

*In general, when one use percent on height, a child's parent also need a height, and if nested, its parent, and so on*

[**Updated codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRaBQM)

```
.navigation ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;

    height: 100%;            /*  added property  */
    margin: 0;               /*  added property  */
}

.navigation li{
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-basis:0;

    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1vw;

    height: 100%;            /*  added property  */
}

.navigation a{
    display: block;
    color: var(--colorTwo);
    background: deepskyblue;

    height: 100%;            /*  added property  */
    display: flex;           /*  added property - center text vertically  */
    align-items: center;     /*  added property - center text vertically  */
    justify-content: center; /*  added property - center text vertically  */
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the text is no longer centered dynamically. As in, if the viewport changes the text goes off center.

Comment: @Omnomnious Yes, missed that ... updated with a solution