# Text inside a div positioned with flex linebreaks before and after certain tags

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

I have been searching around, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what's going on. My text is getting wrapped at certain tags, while I want it all on one line.

I have aligned three DIV elements next to each other through the use of `display: flex;`

This all works out quite nicely and display is exactly the way I want it. Except for the fact that, for some unexplicable reason (at least to me), if I put a text snippet in one of those divs and that text snippet contains something between tags like `<span></span>` or `<b></b>`, the text is automatically wrapped before and after the tag onto a new line.

I have the code here:

```css
.pagetitlewrapper {
 width: 99%;
 background-color: #c1dbff;
 border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.pagetitleleft,.pagetitlecenter,.pagetitleright {
 width: 33%;
 align-items: stretch;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.pagetitleleft {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 9;
}

.pagetitlecenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.pagetitleright {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 9;
 resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
 <div class='pagetitlewrapper'>
  <div class='pagetitleleft'>Welkom, FNAME LNAME</div>
  <div class='pagetitlecenter'><h1>Nexus Consult DMS</h1></div>
  <div class='pagetitleright'>
      Licensed to <span>DON'T WRAP</span> - License valid until xx/xx/xxxx.
  </div>
</div>
```

Around the `DON'T WRAP`, I have put `<span>` tags to illustrate the problem. If you remove these tags, the text is all displayed on one line as I want it. Basically I want to be able to make `DON'T WRAP` bold without it wrapping the text before and after.

I have been searching the web, to no avail. I found a couple of code snippets online which surprisingly did the same thing. I wonder why nobody ran into this problem before?

I have tried to play a bit with `white-space: nowrap;` in CSS, but that didn't seem to work either.

Anyone has any idea? Someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why it break line is because of the `display: flex; flex-direction: column` on the `pagetitleleft/center/right` elements, which make the `span` a flex column item and take 100% width.

By dropping the `display: flex` on the `pagetitleleft/center/right` elements and set `align-items: center` to their parent, their text will center vertically

```css
.pagetitlewrapper {
 width: 99%;
 background-color: #c1dbff;
 border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
 padding: 10px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.pagetitleleft,.pagetitlecenter,.pagetitleright {
 width: 33%;
}

.pagetitleleft {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 9;
}

.pagetitlecenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.pagetitleright {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 9;
 resize: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class='pagetitlewrapper'>
  <div class='pagetitleleft'>Welkom, FNAME LNAME</div>
  <div class='pagetitlecenter'><h1>Nexus Consult DMS</h1></div>
  <div class='pagetitleright'>
      Licensed to <span>DON'T WRAP</span> - License valid until xx/xx/xxxx.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! As I was going through your code, I noticed you had removed a couple of things and it suddenly made sense. There's no point in using `display: flex` in the child div, since nothing inside that div needs to be positioned that way. I'll accept your answer in 2 minutes, when I can!

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39334882). just add `white-space: pre-wrap;`

```
Some-Flex-Container {
  display: flex;
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* solution */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This behavior makes sense and is defined in the flexbox specification.

> [**4. Flex Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a flex container becomes a flex item, and each
>   contiguous run of text that is directly contained inside a flex
>   container is wrapped in an anonymous flex item.

Your right column (`.pagetitleright`) is a flex container with `flex-direction: column`:

```
.pagetitleleft,.pagetitlecenter,.pagetitleright {
   width: 33%;
   align-items: stretch;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

In this container, you have three flex items:

- `<anonymous-flex-item>`Licensed to`</anonymous-flex-item>`
- `<span>`Licensed to`</span>`
- `<anonymous-flex-item>`- License valid until xx/xx/xxxx.`</anonymous-flex-item>`

As a result, you're getting three flex items stacked vertically.

It doesn't matter if you use `span`, `b`, `strong`, `em`. Whatever elements you create in the container become flex items and behave accordingly.

If you don't want these elements to stack vertically, then don't use `flex-direction: column`.

Comment: Hmmm, someone down voted this, which is a good explanation on why the issue occured, so an upvote from me