# display:flex with text and tag inside removes spaces

Tags: css, flexbox

I am developing an advertisement management solution of certain CMS. I provide admin with few locations in the style to position ads in. Admin will input ad code (in HTML: adsense script, banner, or simple text). To make things as easy for admin as possible, I try to center the content automatically by wrapping ad code with this:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
</div>
```

It works perfectly in all cases except for this one:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    Hosting provided by <a href="http://foobar">FooBar Hosting</a> and me
</div>
```

Produces this:

[image]

Note missing spaces between "by FooBar" and "Hosting and". Why is that? Is there any way to fix this with CSS only but retain centering feature for other cases?

Comment: Flex is for layouts not for aligning text.

Comment: Why are you using `display: flex` for that? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The anchor element is a flex items surrounded by two anonymous flex items. To create space between them, use a horizontal margin on `a`. See the answer by @Eytibi below. For a more detailed explanation see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661609/3597276

Comment: *Keen* designers will note that rendering engines are *not* cross-browser compatible when it comes to "vertical alignment" of form and text elements. One should use a parent `span` element with a `flex` (e.g. `flex_row_left`, `flex_column_center`) class and then use `span[class*="flex"] {white-space: pre;}` to maintain the spaces in the child elements. If people built rendering engines properly then no one would have had to ask this question. Furthermore "I don't understand this!" is *not* a valid reason to attempt to invalidate someone else's questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a margin to the a tag.

```css
a {
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
    Hosting provided by <a href="http://foobar">FooBar Hosting</a> and me
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it need to be flex for any reason?

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  Hosting provided by <a href="http://foobar">FooBar Hosting</a> and me
</div>
```

Comment: No it does not. The original intention is to create a bullet-proof centering solution for advertisement codes (AdSense, banners, but custom text as well). Flex works best except for this small issue. Sure, one can wrap text into `<div>` and it's solved. But I try to ease admins that will paste ad codes to CMS.

Comment: @user2908600 so the answer I've given is a solution for you then?

Comment: No it's not. Imagine I just provide a container the admin can insert any HTML. `text-align: center;` works fine for text input. But what if user inserts this:

`<script src="adsense url"></script>`. It won't align now.

I need a bulletproof solution for any possible input.